# How to create sales order custom tab in magento 1.8.0.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have created sales order custom tab.also it display on admin side but template file does not call.

Here is code for adding tab
adminhtml layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>order_view_tab_salesordertab</name>
                 <block>salesordertab/adminhtml_order_view_tab_salesordertab</block>
            </action>
        </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

Block file

```
    class <module>_Salesordertab_Block_Adminhtml_Order_View_Tab_Salesordertab extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface

{    
protected function _constuct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('salesordertab/order/view/tab/salesordertab.phtml');
}

public function getTabLabel() {
    return $this->__('Operater Detail');
}

public function getTabTitle() {
    return $this->__('Operater Detail');
}

public function canShowTab() {
    return true;
}

public function isHidden() {
    return false;
}

public function getOrder(){
    return Mage::registry('current_order');
}
```

}

any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mistake in code.

```
  protected function _construct() /* here construct spell mistake */
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('salesordertab/order/view/tab/salesordertab.phtml');
}
```