# How can i add new tab in sales order view in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

[Reference article](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/)

---

Change the above code snippet to this to add a tab in sales order view

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
       <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
           <action method="addTab">
               <name>my_custom_tab</name>
               <block>customtabs/adminhtml_sales_order_tab</block>
           </action>
       </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

and

```
<?php

class Fishpig_Customtabs_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Tab
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {
```

Important : do change the directory structure

Comment: What is your question here ?

Comment: This seems to be a self-answered question.

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2, Sales Order Page in the admin panel, Many Tabs are available by native like Information, Invoices, Shipments, Credit Memos, Transactions and comment history.

For your custom requirement, you need to add extra tab in Order page, You can add your custom tab in Admin Order View page by just simple module.

You need to create simple module for add extra tab.

Refer below code snippet for add extra tab,
I have taken Rbj as Package name and OrderTab as Modulename for simplicity.
You need to create first **registration.php** and **module.xml** file for defining our module.

Path: **app/code/Rbj/OrderTab/registration.php**

```
<?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Rbj_OrderTab',
   __DIR__
);
```

Create **module.xml** file, Path: **app/code/Rbj/OrderTab/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Rbj_OrderTab" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

We have added the dependency on Magento Sales Module to add the new tab. So we have defined **Magento_Sales** module in sequence tag in the above XML file.

Now comes to the main entry point of a module,
For Add new tab, We must override **sales_order_view.xml** file to add our logic of add custom tabs.

Reference block **sales_order_tabs** contains the tab lists. so we need to create **sales_order_view.xml** file in our module at below path,

Path: **app/code/Rbj/OrderTab/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_tabs</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Rbj\OrderTab\Block\Adminhtml\OrderEdit\Tab\View</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the above file, We have declared Block file for set your custom logic, you want to display in custom tabs.

Create a New Block PHP file, Path: **app/code/Rbj/OrderTab/Block/Adminhtml/OrderEdit/Tab/View.php**

```
<?php
namespace Rbj\OrderTab\Block\Adminhtml\OrderEdit\Tab;

/**
 * Order custom tab
 *
 */
class View extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'tab/view/my_order_info.phtml';

    /**
     * View constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrderId()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getEntityId();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order increment id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrderIncrementId()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('My Custom Tab');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('My Custom Tab');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Above file, We can declare a template file using a **$_template** variable.

protected **$_template = ‘tab/view/my_order_info.phtml’** used for template file for our custom tabs.

You can set Custom Tab label by **getTabLabel**() and set title using **getTabTitle**() function.You can define a custom function for your requirement in the above file.

You can get Current order data by calling **Magento\Framework\Registry** object.

Now we need to create template file,
Path: **app/code/Rbj/OrderTab/view/adminhtml/templates/tab/view/my_order_info.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Rbj\OrderTab\Block\Adminhtml\OrderEdit\Tab\View
 */
?>

<div class="fieldset-wrapper order-information">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">
        <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo __('Information for new Order tab') ?></span>
    </div>
    <table class="admin__table-secondary">
        <tbody>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Order ID:') ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $block->getOrderIncrementId(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Last History:') ?></th>
            <td><?php echo __('History of order') ?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now Run Upgrade command to install our module.

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
**php bin/magento cache:flush**

Now Go To Admin panel, Login with your credentials,
Click on Left Sidebar, **Sales -> Order** Link,
Click on Any Order, You can get the last tab as your new custom tab in Order View page.

Check Custom tab in Sales Order Page,

[image]
[Tnx](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-custom-tab-in-admin-sales-order-view-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Take look @ [Custom tab on sales order view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789216/custom-tab-on-sales-order-view) and [How to create sales order custom tab in magento 1.8.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835199/how-to-create-sales-order-custom-tab-in-magento-1-8-0-1)

Folder structure should be (replace if needed `Fishpig` with the folder name you add to your `local`

> Fishpig_Customtabs_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Tab
>   /app/code/local/Fishpig/Customtabs/[Block/dminhtml/Sales/Order/Tab]